# CustomPainter and CustomClipper produce different outputs for same path

Tags: flutter

I'm using path drawing. I must scale that path. I'm using bounds for scale but It doesn't work same for clipper and painter. I need same output.

Here is codes.

```
    class PaintSvg extends CustomPainter{
  PaintSvg(this.pathStr);

  String pathStr;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint.color = Colors.red;


    Path path = Path();
    path = parseSvgPathData(pathStr);
    Rect pathBounds = path.getBounds();
    Matrix4 matrix4 = Matrix4.identity();

    matrix4.scale(size.width/pathBounds.width, size.height/pathBounds.height);

    path = path.shift(Offset(0,0));
    path = path.transform(matrix4.storage);

    canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.green, 2, true);
    //canvas.rotate(-math.pi/1.18);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

}

class ClipSvg extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  String pathStr;
  ClipSvg(this.pathStr);


  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path = parseSvgPathData(pathStr);
    Rect pathBounds = path.getBounds();
    Matrix4 matrix4 = Matrix4.identity();

    matrix4.scale(size.width/pathBounds.width, size.height/pathBounds.height);
    path = path.transform(matrix4.storage);
    path = path.shift(Offset(0,0));
    return path;

  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(ClipSvg oldClipper) => true;

}
```

Here is output.
[ScreenShot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42sKI.png)

Brown one is clipper red one that behind the brown is painter. Two of them uses same svg data string.

Comment: Btw it's works fine for 2 different svg string I have problem with only one svg strings

Comment: CustomPaint can draw outside the area if you're not careful, maybe adding a canvas.clipPath(//a path to avoid getting out of the size);, there are different clip for the canvas, clipRect and clipRRect

Comment: Idk why but it was all about svg path I create new svg and use thats path It worked.